# Not able to get the value from script in paragraph(<p></p>)

Tags: javascript

```
<p><input type="text" name="adcode" id="cityName" 
         style="border:none;color:green;"/></p>
        <script>
          window.onload = function() {
              document.getElementById('cityName').value = GetDivElement();
            }  
        </script>
```

The above code, I am not able to call the "GetDivElement" in paragraph

```
<p id="cityName"></p>
```

How to pass the GetElementId in p id??

Comment: You cannot have the duplicate ID and where is GetDivElement? Only input elements have `value`, `<p>` would have innerText/innerHTML or textContent

Comment: The `id="cityName"` will be used for the `p` or the `input`?!

Comment: If i understood you correctly , you want to pass getDivElement as the value of the input field ? Can you explain what you want to accomplish with this ? (trigger the function , trigger function on some event )  ?

Comment: Do you need to get the value in the textbox to be appeared in the paragraph?

Comment: if GetDivElement()=coimbatore, the want to get the value in paragraph. I am only able to get the value in textbox. Without textbox I want to get it in <p id="cityName"></p>

Comment: I mean using id="cityName" ,want to get the value in paragraph

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `GetDivElement()` method's return value to the paragraph, you can do it like below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let getDivElement = () => {
    return 'Div element data';
  };
  
  let inputbox = document.getElementById('cityInput');
  let cityParagraph = document.getElementById('cityValue');
  
  inputbox.value = cityParagraph.innerHTML = getDivElement();

}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="cityInput" />
    <p id="cityValue"></p>
</div>
```

As I understood from your later comment, if you want to get the paragraph value if the `id='coimbatore'` which you get from the `GetDivElement()` method you can do the following:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let getDivElement = () => {
    return 'coimbatore';
  };
  
  let paraId = getDivElement();
  let textboxId = `${paraId}CityInput`;
  
  let inputbox = document.getElementById(textboxId);
  let cityParagraph = document.getElementById(paraId);
  
  console.log(`Text field value is : ${inputbox.value}`);
  console.log(`Paragraph value is : ${cityParagraph.innerHTML}`);

}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="delhiCityInput" value="delhi input"/>
    <p id="delhi">
      Delhi city data
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="mumbaiCityInput" value="mumbai input"/>
    <p id="mumbai">
      Mumbai city data
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="coimbatoreCityInput" value="coimbatore input"/>
    <p id="coimbatore">
      Coimbatore city data
    </p>
</div>
```

Couple of things you need to understand here is,

1. You can't set the same id for multiple html elements
2. If you want to get the value from a paragraph you should use `innerHTML`

Hope this helps.